# How can I simulate an anchor click within iframe via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an iframe window that displays a report. To access this iframe, I have an expand/collapse button on the parent window.

Within the iframe report window, I have a #PAGETOP anchor at the bottom of the report, i,e:

```
<tr><td style="padding-left:45px" class="bottom" colspan="99"><div id="ptAnchor"><a href="#PAGETOP"><img src="first.png" border="1" alt="Top of Page" /></a></div></td></tr>
```

How can I programatically emulate an onclick of this #PAGETOP anchor, when the user presses the "expand" button from the parent window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `#PAGETOP` anchor is to scroll the window to the top. You can instead write a function to scroll the window to 0,0 coordinates.

```
function ScrollToTop() {
    window.scroll(0, 0);
}
```

Put this function in the IFrame, and call it from the parent window.

Comment: Hi Kirtan, unfortunately this didn't seem to work. Would still appreciate how I would do this progrmatically - thanks.

Comment: Any such fix requires the same domain in the src of the iframe.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

In the parent doc:

```
<a id="scrollToTop">Expand</a>
<script type="text/javascript">

   document.getElementById("scrollToTop").onclick = function(e) { 
      var childWindow =  document.getElementById("theIFrame").contentWindow;

      // this should emulate a click on the ptAnchor DIV's child A HREF.
      childWindow.document.getElementById("ptAnchor").firstChild.click();

      // alternatively, this will simply scroll the child window to the top-left corner
      childWindow.scrollTo(0,0);
   }
</script>
<iframe id="theIFrame" src="someDocOnTheSameDomain.html"></iframe>
```

Your iframe must be on the same domain for the browser to allow scripting between the parent and child frames.

The **contentWindow** property allows you to access the window object of the child iframe.  From there, you can write Javascript to emulate a click or simply scroll the window around.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<iframe name="foo"></iframe>
<button>Expand</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
      window.frames['foo'].location.hash = "top";
    });
  });
</script>
```